# Firebase Cannot resolve method 'getEditText' in 'EditText'

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to make a app where you can store information into the Firebase Real Time Database. But when I watched a tutorial there was a error whit mine.

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnTerug, btnGo;
    EditText codeIdt, codeItt;

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        btnTerug = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTerug);
        codeIdt = findViewById(R.id.codeId);
        codeItt = findViewById(R.id.codeIt);
        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

        //Save data in Database
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                reference = rootNode.getReference("Bungalows");

                //Get all the values
                String codeId = codeIdt.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String codeIt = codeItt.getEditText().getText().toString();

                DataSaver helperClass = new DataSaver(codeId,codeIt);

                reference.setValue(helperClass);
            }
            });
```

Both the .getEditText() gives a error: `Cannot resolve method 'getEditText' in 'EditText'`

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
String codeId = codeIdt.getText().toString();
String codeIt = codeItt.getText().toString();
```